# Digital Signature Verification failed using SHA256withRSA in Python

Tags: encryption, rsa, public-key

I am trying to validate the digital signature with given certificate files for the offline aadhaar KYC verification application.

This instruction is given in the documentation for the verification.

> 1. Read the entire XML and separate the s=”xxxx” tag from it.
> 2. Use a signature validation algorithm leveraging “SHA256withRSA” based hashing and encryption technique
> 3. Signature value present in “s” tag, remaining XML (without "s" tag) and UIDAI public key (available here.) is to be fed to the algorithm to validate the digital signature.

**Sample C# code snippets provided by the organization. (PS :which is also not working**)

```
using System;
using System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates;
using System.Xml;

namespace test
{
class MainClass
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        // link -> https://drive.google.com/file/d/1aSv3HJUFf5_42Z-FqpdVHEk5b3VA3T3D/view


        string XMLFilePath = "offlineaadhaar.xml"; //Get the XML file
        
// link -> https://drive.google.com/file/d/1FW4ciIhZqJuelOcGF2x6VaBCSDO9J-gM/view


string KeyFilePath = "okyc-publickey.cer"; //Get the public key certificate file

        XmlDocument ObjXmlDocument = new XmlDocument();
        ObjXmlDocument.Load(XMLFilePath); //Load the XML
        XmlAttributeCollection SignatureElement = ObjXmlDocument.DocumentElement.Attributes; //Get the all XML attribute
        string SignatureValue = SignatureElement.GetNamedItem("s").InnerXml; // Get Signature value

        SignatureElement.RemoveNamedItem("s");//Remove the signature "s" attribute from XML and get the new XML to validate

        /*----------------Read and parse the public key as string-----------------------*/
        X509Certificate2 ObjX509Certificate2 = new X509Certificate2(KeyFilePath, "public"); //Initialize the public ket certificate file

        Org.BouncyCastle.X509.X509Certificate objX509Certificate;
        Org.BouncyCastle.X509.X509CertificateParser objX509CertificateParser = new Org.BouncyCastle.X509.X509CertificateParser();

        objX509Certificate = objX509CertificateParser.ReadCertificate(ObjX509Certificate2.GetRawCertData());
        /*----------------End-----------------------*/

        /* Init alg */
        Org.BouncyCastle.Crypto.ISigner signer = Org.BouncyCastle.Security.SignerUtilities.GetSigner("SHA256withRSA");

        /* Populate key */
        signer.Init(false, objX509Certificate.GetPublicKey());

        /* Get the signature into bytes */
        var expectedSig = Convert.FromBase64String(SignatureValue);

        /* Get the bytes to be signed from the string */
        var msgBytes = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(ObjXmlDocument.InnerXml);


        /* Calculate the signature and see if it matches */
        signer.BlockUpdate(msgBytes, 0, msgBytes.Length);
        bool Flag = signer.VerifySignature(expectedSig);            
        if (Flag)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("XML Validate Successfully");
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("XML Validation Failed");
        }
    }
}
}
```

I am trying to implement in Python and getting the XML validation failed. I am not sure if the certificate file is wrong or there is some bug on my code.

Here is my Python Code :

```
import xml
import xml.etree.cElementTree as etree
from xml.etree import ElementTree
import OpenSSL
from cryptography import x509
from cryptography.hazmat.backends import default_backend
from Crypto.PublicKey import RSA
from base64 import b64encode, b64decode
from M2Crypto import BIO, RSA, EVP

xmlDoc = open('adhar.xml', 'r').read()
Tr = etree.XML(xmlDoc)
Tr.keys()
# ['s', 'r', 'a', 'g', 'm', 'e', 'd', 'i', 'n', 'v']

sign = Tr.get('s')
len(sign)
# 344

del Tr.attrib['s']

from M2Crypto import X509

x509 =X509.load_cert('ekyc_public_key.cer')
#x509 =X509.load_cert(cert4)
rsa = x509.get_pubkey().get_rsa()
pubkey = EVP.PKey()
pubkey.assign_rsa(rsa)

xmlstr = etree.tostring(Tr, encoding='utf8', method='xml')
#rstr=str(xmlstr)[45:][:-1]
#rstr = rstr.encode(encoding='utf-8')


# if you need a different digest than the default 'sha1':
pubkey.reset_context(md='sha256')
pubkey.verify_init()

# hashlib.sha256(message_without_sign).digest()
pubkey.verify_update(xmlstr)
if(pubkey.verify_final(b64decode(sign)) != 1):
    print('Digital Signeture not validated')
else: 
    print('Digital Signeture validated')
```

Comment: Complete code available on github https://github.com/chinmaydas96/Offline_aadhaar_XML_verification/blob/master/Decrypt.py

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In cryptography, the devil is in the details, like what really is meant by:

> remaining XML (without "s" tag)

We are lucky: this ridiculously vague specification <strike>comes</strike> came with a [sample XML file](https://uidai.gov.in/images/offlineaadhaar20181115055017542.xml) and matching [certificate](https://uidai.gov.in/images/okyc-publickey.cer), allowing to:

- extract the signature signature field (converted from Base64 to binary) from the former to get *S*;
- extract *N* and *e* from the later;
- compute *V* = *S* <sup>*e*</sup> mod *N*
- check that *V* is indeed formatted per SHA256withRSA (also known as [RSASSA-PKCS1-v1_5](https://www.emc.com/collateral/white-papers/h11300-pkcs-1v2-2-rsa-cryptography-standard-wp.pdf#page=31) with SHA-256 hash),
- on the right of *V* after a fixed DER prefix `3031300d060960864801650304020105000420` characteristic of a Digestinfo with SHA-256 we extract the 32-byte value `f4efef8c788058df45385ec65a49e92f806b9ffd6fc6d11b4f3c2cf89a81fe2f`, which thus is the expected hash for that example's signed data.

So with a little trial and error we find what that signed data really is. We want to start from XML file and remove

1. the `s` tag
2. its `=` (and, should there be any, whitespace between former `s` tag and `=`, and after `=` as allowed by the XML syntax)
3. its value field including leading and closing `"` (which contains the base64-encoded signature)
4. **precisely two nearby space characters**, like the one before the `s` tag and the one after the closing `"` (alternatively, we might want to leave a single space where there are now several, probably three after the removals in bullet points 1-3).

then hash what remains including `< />` delimiters (as UTF-8), that is in the sample code pass it to `BlockUpdate` or `verify_update`. For that example:

```
<OKV v="1"  n="Ravi Krishna Nalagatla"  i="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"  d="10121993" e="ac342bb947d5aa49847a0a05f87c388759a6cb156e04eac6ae995e9dca5ba1d9" m="254618fd06a2e7308247c7f0fb547f58174ab3b99e7b042d6705a5457235f32a"  g="male"  a="S/O Narasimham, 45, 74, 4, 7, Secunderabad, Hyderabad, Andhra Pradesh - 500003" r="328020181115111938451" />
```

Update: sample XML, certificate, and the above are in this [zip archive](http://mpqs.free.fr/offlineaadhaar_test_data.zip).

Comment: Yes, that was the main issue. Thanks for that. It is solved now.

Comment: Ugh, you are a lucky guy that fgrieu was into puzzling yesterday :)

Comment: @ChinmayDas can you help in it, kindly see answer

Answer (score 3):

For this project, all the instructions can be found on this [page](https://uidai.gov.in/ecosystem/authentication-devices-documents/about-aadhaar-paperless-offline-e-kyc.html) in *Steps to validate signature* step.

Sample data, sample public key and sample c# code can be found on this [page](https://uidai.gov.in/ecosystem/authentication-devices-documents/about-aadhaar-paperless-offline-e-kyc.html?id=11307#tab4) in *Offline ekyc Sample data* tab.

For your own data please refer to this [link](https://resident.uidai.gov.in/offlineaadhaar) and download the zip file and extract it.

Here is the ekyc public key for the other xml validation [ekyc_public_key.cer](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1M26FjQ6jgHdCXtn4IGOjqqCvJkvJD7Ti/view?usp=sharing)

Please find the complete answer in below code snippet which is implemented in python :

```
from M2Crypto import BIO, RSA, EVP
from M2Crypto import X509

# 'ekyc_public_key.cer' for own your own data. as 'okyc_public_key.cer' only work for sample data only

x509 =X509.load_cert('okyc_public_key.cer')
rsa = x509.get_pubkey().get_rsa()
pubkey = EVP.PKey()
pubkey.assign_rsa(rsa)


import lxml.etree as le

with open(xml_path,'r') as f:
    doc=le.parse(f)
    for elem in doc.xpath('//*[attribute::s]'):
        sign = elem.attrib['s']
        elem.attrib.pop('s')    
data_str = str(le.tostring(doc))[2:][:-1]

data = data_str[:-2] +  ' />'

pubkey.reset_context(md='sha256')
pubkey.verify_init()

pubkey.verify_update((data_str[:-2] +  ' />').encode())

is_valid_signeture = ""
if(pubkey.verify_final(b64decode(sign)) != 1):
    print('Digital Signeture not validated')
    is_valid_signeture = 'Invalid'
else: 
    print('Digital Signeture validated') 
    is_valid_signeture = 'Valid'
```

Comment: Complete code available at https://github.com/chinmaydas96/Offline_aadhaar_XML_verification/blob/master/Decrypt.py

Answer (score 0):

More about XML signing [here](https://users.dcc.uchile.cl/~pcamacho/tutorial/web/xmlsec/xmlsec.html)

Python Code for Digital Signature verification for new Aadhar XML:

```
certificate_file  = "uidai_offline_publickey_19062019.cer"
aadhar_file = "offlineaadhaar20200120032019978.xml"
certificate = open(certificate_file, "rb").read()
aadhar_xml = open(aadhar_file, "rb").read()
from signxml import XMLSigner, XMLVerifier
try:
    verify_result = XMLVerifier().verify(aadhar_xml, x509_cert=certificate)
    # return True
except Exception as e: 
    verify_result = None
    # return False
    print(e)
```

You can download the certificate from [here](https://uidai.gov.in/images/authDoc/uidai_offline_publickey_19062019.cer).

More about signxml [here](https://pypi.org/project/signxml/).